# Excel: Conditionally Select Range of Cells Based on Values in Other Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can do things like this:  `=SUM($E2:$E1916)` or `=MEDIAN($E2:$E1916)`

I'd like to perform the arithmetic on a subset of column E based on the values in another column.   So, in column H the cells have a value of "Ford", "GMC", "Chrysler", "Toyota", "Honda" or "Subaru".

I want the sum or median or similar operation on column E to only select the cells in col E where the corresponding value in column H is "Toyota", "Honda" or "Subaru".

So the formula would look something like

```
=SUM(if($H2:$H1916={"Toyota","Honda","Subaru"},$E2:$E1916))
```

But that formula gives an answer of zero.

Comment: Look into the function `SUMIFS()`: https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

Comment: @Hakan ERDOGAN Thanks for the edit; it improves it.   Thx for the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just an <kbd>Enter</kbd> since it should be functioning as an array formula by construction.

But if you don't want to use an array formula you may construct a SUM formula as follows:

```
=SUMIFS($E2:$E1916, $H2:$H1916, "Toyota")+SUMIFS($E2:$E1916, $H2:$H1916, "Honda") + SUMIFS($E2:$E1916, $H2:$H1916, "Subaru")
```

- The first parameter is the values to be summed. You may use E:E instead.
- 2nd parameter is the column which contains all the values which will be compared to our criteria.
- 3rd parameter is our criteria.

Comment: Thanks.  Ctrl Shft Enter did it.  And after I'd done that once, any time  something causes formulas in general to be recalcualted, that formula is correctly refreshed too.   Great!!   Thank you.